# The properness of a submersion

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be two differential manifolds and there is a surjective submersion $f$ from $M$ to $N$ such that $f^{-1}(p)$ is compact and connected for any $p$ on $N$. Can we conclude that $f$ is proper, that is, the preimage of a compact set is compact?

It is also posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004543/13534

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem to me.  I've voted to close.

Comment: Without tryng to judge one way or another whether it's homework, it is the *type* of thing that has been discussed at math.stackexchange, e.g., here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/proper-maps-and-families-of-compact-complex-manifolds If OP cannot construct an argument from that or similar threads, he should probably ask over there. (I happen to think it's a good question.)

Comment: @Todd Trimble, I am afraid the answers in that Math.StackExchange discussion get us no closer to an answer to this question. They seem to be mostly wrong as far as I can tell.

Comment: This has been asked also at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004543/the-properness-of-a-submersion (and then deleted by the OP; but I undeleted it)

Comment: **Please** if after some time you do not get an answer in math.stackexchange.com it can be sensible to reask here, but *always* provide links to the other question in both sides, and **please** do not delete questions which have answers on which other users have spent time and energy.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Thanks for checking. I didn't have time earlier to take a proper look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is true in greater generality. If $M$ and $N$ are locally compact, and the fibers of $f$ are compact connected and $f$ is a quotient map then f is proper. This falls under the rubric of monotone light factorization. Look at the book of G.T. Whyburn and E. Duda titled Dynamic Topology. Monotone Light factorization says if a map between locally compact Hausdorff has the property, that all connected components of all fibers are compact, then the map can be factored as a proper map onto a space with connected fibers and this space maps to the co-domain with totally disconnected fibers. Thanks to Dan Petersen and Richard Andrade for correction. 
Addendum:
 Let a connected component of the fiber of a map be called a level.Suppose X and Y are locally compact Hausdorff spaces and F a continuous map such that all levels are compact .Suppose the equivalence relation R on X is given by saying x and y are equivalent if they lie in the same level, then R is a proper equivalence relation
and the map from X to X/R is proper with connected fibers and F factors through X/R to Y as a map with totally disconnected fibers . In the case of the question of
the OP the equivalence relation R and the one given by f coincide and therefore the map is proper

Comment: Nice answer, Mohan.

Comment: I don't think this completely answers the question. Consider e.g. $\mathbf R\setminus \{0\} \sqcup \{0\}$ with its natural map to $\mathbf R$, which is a nonproper map with compact connected fibers. To rule out a silly counterexample like this it seems one should use the submersion hypothesis (which your argument doesn't).

Comment: The spaces in Dan Petersen's example *are* locally connected. You may want to require that the map be (at least) a quotient map.

Comment: In Dan's case the intermediate space is just the space he started with .The identity map is proper.

Comment: What I meant is that Dan's comment still provides a counter-example to the second sentence in your answer. On another note, the spaces before the periods in your answer are kind of confusing. The spaces should usually come *after* the periods.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade Your last comment on Dan's example contradicting the second sentence is a little hard to follow: his identity map (at the underlying set level) is certainly not a quotient map. Could be wires were getting crossed.

Comment: @Todd That is my fault. I added the quotient map in my hypothesis after Dan's example.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: Mohan has fixed the hypotheses by now. Nevertheless, what I meant was that without the hypothesis that f is a quotient map, the second sentence of Mohan's answer was wrong: Dan's comment provided a counter-example to the statement. I think the rest of the answer does not require the hypothesis that f is a quotient map.